# C# Reflection, setting new instance of a null property

Tags: c#, reflection, null, instance

I've writing a small method whose sole purpose is to check if a property is null for a given class. If the property is null, then create a new instance of it. I'm getting stuck on part where I'm actually setting a value:

```
  public static void CheckIfPropertyIsNull<TEntity>(SomeBusinessEntity someBusinessEntity) where TEntity : new()
    {
        var properties = typeof(SomeBusinessEntity).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            Type currentType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
            if (currentType == typeof(TEntity))
            {
                var propertyData = propertyInfo.GetValue(someBusinessEntity, null);
                if (propertyData == null)

                {
                    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TEntity));

                    // And then?
                    //propertyInfo.SetValue(null, instance);

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I try to use the SetValue() method but with no luck.

Comment: You've gone to the bother of requesting from the generics system that any type you're supplied has a parameterless constructor - so why not just `new TEntity()` rather than `Activator.CreateInstance(...)`?

Comment: I had some thought process and was just doodling around with the code. I was using new TEntity() before.

Answer (score 5):

In your `SetValue` you still have to give the instance of the owner of the property: `someBusinessEntity`.

```
object instance = new TEntity();

// And then
propertyInfo.SetValue(someBusinessEntity, instance);
```

Note that your logic seems odd to me. You are using a generic type to set all properties. Why not use the type of the property?

Comment: Thank you Patrick. It works. Im quite new to reflection and don't quite understand your last part.